# Can't combine col selection with CSV conversion

Tags: csv, jq

I've successfully been using jq for a while now, to take a JSON payload, select some of the columns, re-name the columns, and finally, create a JSON file. This is awesome bc I do not need a majority of the columns in the input dataset. Here is an example of one of those working commands:

```
curl -s https://c2.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-bulk/default-cards/default-cards-20220314210303.json
| jq '[.[] | {oracle_id: .oracle_id, scryfall_id: .id, rarity: .rarity, set_code: .set, latest_price: .prices.usd, scryfall_url: .scryfall_uri, art_crop_url: .image_uris.art_crop, is_digital: .digital, is_promo: .promo, is_variation: .variation}]' > Desktop/printings.json
```

However, what I really need is to have this data in CSV format. I have been manually working around this by feeding the output of the command above into a free web tool for converting to CSV. But I recently learned that jq can output CSV itself, so I would like to streamline this so I can just get CSV data from jq in the first place. I read the jq documentation, and reviewed several Stack Overflow threads to learn how this works. But none of the examples I've found for generating CSV data with jq involve selecting specific columns or re-naming those columns. So I've not been able to get this to work.

I tried this command below, where I am attempting to 1) read in the JSON file from the scryfall.com endpoint, then 2) map the keys as rows and columns to prep to convert to the CSV format, and 3) apply a filter selecting each of the 10 columns I need. (I could not figure out the column re-naming part, so I removed that part for now, for the sake of simplicity):

```
curl -s https://c2.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-bulk/default-cards/default-cards-20220314210303.json
| jq -r '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | .oracle_id | .id | .rarity | .set | .prices.usd | .scryfall_uri | .image_uris.art_crop | .digital | .promo | .variation |  @csv' > Desktop/printings.csv
```

The result is this error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:67121): Cannot index array with string "oracle_id"
```

I'm not sure why "| .oracle_id" would be indexing anything. My intent is to filter the data. However, I think my struggle is an algorithmic one. Should I try to use pipes to sequence the different steps of selecting columns and generating the csv? Or should I combine them? If I need to separate the steps, what order do they  need to come in? I understnad that the @csv filter at the end must take an array as input, but that's where I start to lose the plot.

Since the input JSON file is a freely-available, public dataset, you should be able to try this out to see if you get the same error output I showed above.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should try breaking out each "group" and testing separately, to see if it is mapping as you expect it to.

`$cols` maps out all the keys across all records while `$rows` are all the values of the records. You already have the rows and records you wanted so pass to `@csv`. Though keep in mind arrays passed to `@csv` must be all strings.

```
(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols
  | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.] | tostring)) as $rows
  | $cols, $rows[]
  | @csv
```

This however selects all mapped columns. If you only want a subset of them, just change the `$cols` variable to be what columns you want from the data. You might want to separate the value mapping from this since you have some nested values.

```
["oracle_id", "id", "rarity", "set", "price", "scryfall_uri", "image_uri", "digital", "promo", "variation"],
(.[] | [.oracle_id, .id, .rarity, .set, .prices.usd, .scryfall_uri, .image_uris.art_crop, .digital, .promo, .variation])
  | @csv
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/HjafYv4i58)

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you for your fast response! I ran the command to map the keys:

*code*curl -s https://c2.scryfall.com/file/scryfall-bulk/default-cards/default-cards-20220314210303.json | jq -r '(map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.] | tostring)) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv' > Desktop/Printings.csv*code*

and I manually removed all the cols except the 10 I want. The dataset has ~67k rows, so of course I can't inspect every cell. However, I did skim over the data in each column and I don't see anything out of place there.

Comment: Next, I did isolate and test with each of the 10 cols individually. When I did, jq threw the same error claiming there is an issue with every col? Errors were like:

jq: error (at <stdin>:67121): Cannot index string with string "oracle_id";
jq: error (at <stdin>:67121): Cannot index string with string "id";
jq: error (at <stdin>:67121): Cannot index string with string "rarity";
etc, etc,

Comment: 67121 is the last row of the file btw. It seems very unlikely that there is a problem in the input JSON data, in every one of the cols. Also, when I generate the CSV using the mapping, grabbing all 87(!) cols, jq is able to successfully output the file. But as soon as I try to select cols, it breaks.

Comment: I'd try downloading the full file then running the query against that. It seems fine to me running against the full input. Perhaps it was getting corrupted somewhere.